# ZeroMq Pub Sub Address not Available

Tags: c#, messaging, zeromq

I'm creating a pub sub style communication using zeromq c# implementation. It all works fine on my local machine but when running the client component (publisher) against a remote address I get an "Address not available". So far as I understand it the Publisher will Bind to an endpoint and the Subscriber will Connect.

Am I misunderstanding something or should publisherSocket.Bind("tcp://someRemoteIP:5001") work?

Comment: In general, 0mq socket can bind only to local addresses of host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You bind to a local endpoint, and connect to a remote endpoint.

The local endpoint consists of a protocol ("tcp://"), an interface ("*", "localhost", "eth0" (or such) or the IP address of an interface), and a port number (":5001").

The remote endpoint consists of a protocol ("tcp://"), an IP address or domain name ("someremoteIP") and the port number.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For Windows, `tcp://*:5001` worked for me, but `tcp://10.7.40.93:5001` did not work for me (nothing happened) (where 10.7.50.93 is the IP address of the local machine), although the documentation suggests that using the IP address of the local adapter is the way to select a particular adapter. `eth0` et al only work on Linux.